# Excel x64 file corruption in .xlsb files for Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, 64-bit, macros, file-corruption

I have a number of Excel files, all created in Office x64, all in .xlsb format and all containing macros. Every now and again, these files become corrupted and I cannot get them to run. I can however open them in safe mode, but when I enable 'active content' i.e. the macros, the file crashes.

The only fix I have found is for someone running x32 to open the file, resave it, and send it back to me. Then the file opens and runs fine. I understand that this was an issue in Excel 2010 (article [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55fe29f6-4e80-4ff5-876e-9d1d46e7975f/microsoft-excel-has-stopped-working64bit-windows-7-64bit-excel-2010?forum=excel)), but **can anyone provide me with more information on how to permanently fix this issue?**

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: @Ramhound - Done

Comment: But won't that defeat the purpose of having macros?

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have never come across an xlsx file containing vba. template files, xlsm, addins, and xlsb only

Comment: Have you tried saving the file after opening them in Safe mode, then reopening regularly?

Comment: @Kyle - Yes. Unfortunately, no love.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg - Please do not ping people against 2 year old comments in the future.